# Unable to join a list of string

Tags: python

From a list of list `(list = [ ['OS', 'Homo', ...], ...])`, I wanted to store only the data on the species. I could store the list `line_species` but I am unable to join it in order to create a string.

```
line_species = ['Homo', 'sapiens', '(Human).']
```

Wanted : `string = "Homo sapiens (Human)"`

```
def recup_species(data):
    line_species=[]
    for line in data :
        if line[0] == 'OS': 
            line_species = line_species + line[1:]
            " ".join(line_species)  # doesn't work
    return line_species
```

Any advice to help me ?

Comment: `" ".join(line_species)` Doesn't do anything, because you're not assigning it to anything.

Comment: As above mentioned, unless you return the join results : `return " ".join(line_species)`

Comment: `join` does not mutate its argument, as you're apparently expecting.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the result of your joining:

```
def recup_species(data):
    line_species=[]
    for line in data :
        if line[0] == 'OS': 
            line_species = line_species + line[1:]
    return " ".join(line_species)
```

`str.join` doesn't modify the iterable you're handing it.